# On startup, where does the output to dmesg get logged?

Tags: logging, dmesg

On startup, where does the output to dmesg get logged?

Doesn't say on the man page:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dmesg.1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `kernel`'s operation related messages are stored in a fixed sized memory called the `Kernel Ring Buffer`. It's location is `/proc/kmsg`. `dmesg` usually prints the entries of the `Kernel Ring Buffer` in a human readable format. As it is a buffer (a temporary storage) mounted under `/proc`, you can imagine that it will not survive a reboot i.e. it will just show all the Kernel logs after being powered On. If you want to check all the previous Kernel logs you need to check `/var/log/kern.log`, as it is being stored on the disk it will survive the reboots.